# Ionic 1 with Firebase 3 - Update form

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to ionic, angular and firebase. Can someone show me an example of an update or edit form ?  I have a list of items that has 3 fields each. The user clicks on the list item it goes to an edit form.

How can I update just one or two of the fields ? If I don't update all of them I get an error, undefined in property. So if I update year it will error out and say make is undefined in property.

```
<label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label">
Year
</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="{{cars.year}}" ng-model="data.year">
</label> 
<label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label">
Make
</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="{{cars.make}}" ng-model="data.make">
</label>        
<label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label">
Model
</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="{{cars.model}}" ng-model="data.model">
</label>
```

Controller

```
$scope.updateCar = function () {
                firebase.database().ref('users/' + $scope.user + '/cars/' +         $scope.key).set({
                   year:  $scope.data.year,
                   make:    $scope.data.make,
                   model:  $scope.data.model

                });
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429814/update-data-if-exist-in-firebase
It's worked for me.