# Update data if exist in firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update a data if it exists

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('users');
var refUserId = firebase.database().ref().child('users').orderByChild('id').equalTo(Auth.$getAuth().uid);
refUserId.once('value', function (snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot);
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          snapshot.ref().update(vm.user_infos);
        } else {
        ref.push({
          player: vm.user_infos.player,
          id: vm.user_infos.id
        }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
  }
});
```

Push is working fine, but the update did not.

> snapshot.ref is not a function

In the snapshot () log console:

[image]

I tried this way too:

```
if (snapshot.exists()) {
    refUserId.update({
      player: vm.user_infos.player,
      id: vm.user_infos.id
    }, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
})
```

Result:

> refUserId.update is not a function

User structure

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that the snapshot's [`ref` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#ref) is an object - not a function.

The second is that the snapshot refers to the `users` path, so you should check for a user that matches your query like this:

```js
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('users');
var refUserId = ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(Auth.$getAuth().uid);
refUserId.once('value', function (snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
      child.ref.update(vm.user_infos);
    });
  } else {
    snapshot.ref.push({
      player: vm.user_infos.player,
      id: vm.user_infos.id
    });
  }
});
```

And if you want to know when the `update` or `push` has completed, you could use promises:

```js
refUserId
  .once('value')
  .then(function (snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
      return snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
        child.ref.update(vm.user_infos);
      });
    } else {
      return snapshot.ref.push({
        player: vm.user_infos.player,
        id: vm.user_infos.id
      });
    }
  })
  .then(function () {
    console.log('update/push done');
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. But after the update, instead of updating the information it creates a new 
 http://imgur.com/a/kDNwY

Comment: Thank you. I just modified it in your code: child.ref().update(vm.user_infos); for this: child.ref.update(vm.user_infos);

Worked well